# Counting particular odd-length strings over a two letter alphabet.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words, oeis

OEIS sequence [A297789](https://oeis.org/A297789) describes

> The number of [equivalence classes of] length $2n - 1$ strings over the alphabet $\{0, 1\}$  such that the first half of any initial odd-length substring is a permutation of the second half.
>
> Two strings are in the same equivalence class if they are the same up to swapping the letters of the alphabet.
>
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 17, 25, 49, 75, 129, 191, 329, 489, 825, 1237, 2473, 3737, 6329, 9435, 16833, 25081, 41449, 61043, 115409, 172441, 290617

For example, $1010110101101$ is such a string because:

```
initial odd substring | first half | second half
----------------------+------------+------------
  1                   | 1          | 1
  101                 | 10         | 01
  10101               | 101        | 101
  1010110             | 1010       | 0110
  101011010           | 10101      | 11010
  10101101011         | 101011     | 101011
  1010110101101       | 1010110    | 0101101
```

---

## Question

I have two conjectures based on the first few terms:

- $A297789(2^k + 1) = 2\cdot A297789(2^k) - 1$ for $k > 0$, and
- $A297789(n)$ is odd for all $n > 4$.

Is there a proof or counter-example to these conjectures?

---

It's worth noting that the strings that A297789 counts can be put on a binary tree. Perhaps this is a useful lens?

[image: A297789 Tree]

Comment: Why no strings starting with 0?

Comment: Technically the sequence counts equivalence classes, where two strings are in the same equivalence class if they’re the same under swapping letters of the alphabet.

Comment: Shouldn't the definition either mention the equivalence classes or, more simply, say something like "strings starting with 1?"

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof of the first conjecture.

#### Preliminary remarks

Let's call "balanced strings" those described by that sequence.

Let $s$ be a balanced binary string of length $2n-1$. We denote $s_i$ its $i$-th bit (indexed from $1$), and $s_i^j$ the substring of bits from $i$ to $j$ (inclusive). The number of $1$ is denoted $|s|$.

Note that another way to say that two binary strings are permutations of each other is that they have the same numbers of $0$ and $1$:
$s$ being balanced is equivalent to saying that for every $i < n$, $|s_1^n| = |s_n^{2n-1}|$.

This implies that every odd prefix is also balanced. Conversely, we can generate balanced strings by appending two bits at a time. This is also suggested by the binary tree you drew above.

How many ways are there to extend $s$ into a balanced string of length $2(n+1)-1$? We enumerate pairs of bits, $s_{2n}$ and $s_{2n+1}$, such that $|s_1^{n+1}| = |s_{n+1}^{2n+1}|$. We must consider four cases of the possible values for the middle bits $s_n$ and $s_{n+1}$. Here's one:

- If $s_n = 0$ and $s_{n+1} = 1$, then

  $$\begin{aligned}
     |s_1^{n+1}| &= |s_1^n| + 1 \\
                 &= |s_n^{2n-1}| + 1 \quad \text{(since $s$ is balanced)}\\
                 &= |s_{n+1}^{2n-1}| + 1
  \end{aligned}$$

  For that to be equal to $|s_{n+1}^{2n+1}|$, the new bits can be either $01$ or $10$ (two choices).

The conclusion is that if $s_n \neq s_{n+1}$, then there are two ways to extend $s$ (with $01$ or $10$), otherwise there is only one.

#### Main result

> $A297789(2^k+1)=2⋅A297789(2^{k})−1$ for $k>0$

As a consequence of the previous intermediate result, that is equivalent to claiming that every balanced string of length $2^{k+1}-1$ can be extended in exactly two ways, except the one string made of all ones.

That, in turn, amounts to saying that in every balanced string $s$ of length $2^{k+1}-1$, the middle bits $s_{2^k}$ and $s_{2^k+1}$ are distinct. In that case, the new bits we append at the end are $01$ or $10$, i.e., also distinct. Interesting coincidence, we can thus prove that claim by induction on $k$.